# libGL error: failed to load drivers iris and swrast in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, python, 22.04, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm trying to run a pong game (pygame) in Python (VSCode) using  a conda environment and I get this:

```
pygame 2.3.0 (SDL 2.24.2, Python 3.9.16)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  161
  Current serial number in output stream:  162
```

Comment: Is this a Ubuntu or for that matter any Linux compatible game? Where did you get it from? What is the exact command that produced this error?

Answer (score 0):

The same problem, and its solution, are explained at [stackoverflow | Cannot load `swrast` and `iris` drivers in Fedora 35](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71010344/6079195). Basically you need to force loading the libstdc++.so.6 in your system with precedence over another version.
To locate this file in your filesystem:
`find / -name libstdc++.so.6 2>/dev/null`
Then add the export LD_PRELOAD to the .bashrc file, e.g.:
`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 0):

In my case of `python-vlc` and `pygame`, it is anaconda3/miniconda3's problem. I have two miniconda3 environments, one is old, one is new. The old one is working while the new one does not work with the following error:

```
xuancong@mx:~/projects/*$ ./miniconda3/bin/python -i debug.py 
>>> libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  44
```

So I used `lsof -p <PID>` to poke all dynamic libraries that is used. It turns out that the problem lies in `miniconda3/lib/libffi*.so`.
The old conda environment (working) has:

```
67214 Jul  7  2020 libffi.a
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so.6 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Apr 28  2022 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
50664 Jul  7  2020 libffi.so.7.1.0
```

while the new conda environment (not working) has:

```
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.7.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.8.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
 97758 May 10  2023 libffi.a
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
    15 Jan 31 17:14 libffi.so.8 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
 72144 May 10  2023 libffi.so.8.1.2
```

The root cause of this error turns out to be that `libffi.so.8` is not downward compatible with `libffi.so.7`, so that you cannot simply soft-link all versions of `libffi.so` to `libffi.so.8`. So all I did was to copy over `libffi.so.7.1.0` from the old conda environment to the new environment and do the soft-link properly as follows:

```
   15 Jan 31 17:03 libffi.7.so -> libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Jan 31 09:48 libffi.8.so -> libffi.so.8.1.2
97758 May 10  2023 libffi.a
   15 Jan 31 17:09 libffi.so -> libffi.so.8
   15 Jan 31 17:17 libffi.so.7 -> libffi.so.7.1.0
50664 Jan 31 17:02 libffi.so.7.1.0
   15 Jan 31 09:48 libffi.so.8 -> libffi.so.8.1.2
72144 May 10  2023 libffi.so.8.1.2
```

And then everything runs correctly. Take note that you can still link the default `libffi.so` to the highest version, i.e., `libffi.so -> libffi.so.8`, it will still work.